# Django popup window for Inlines

Tags: django, inline, admin

I've got a problem here. I've got three models, A, B and C.

```
Class A

Class B
    fb = foreignkey(A)

Class C
    fc = foreignkey(B)
```

In admin.py I'm doing something like

```
AdminA
    inlines = [inlineB]

AdminB
    inlines = [inlineC]
```

The troubles start appearing on Add page of Model A. Basically, Model B is just a placeholder for different manytomany and foreignfields, and doesn't have any internal fields of its own. So although I'm able to add inline for Model B, I'm unable to add any features to it. I was hoping to find a way to get a popup window link in Inline rows. Something similar to the popup window thats opens when one needs to create a foreginkey. Any ideas?

Comment: I have seen the same issue. Personally I would like a way to just get a popup for anything you to to CRUD an inline, and then just show them inline with links.